# DB2 cluster on Kubernetes

Tags: db2, containers, kubernetes

Has any one tried configuring the DB2 cluster on Kubernetes? If so could you please share the details? How did you achieve the Sared disk / HADR on kubernetes? Any specific tools used?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if https://dba.stackexchange.com would be a better fit?  However, in any case this seems quite broad.  One or more better focused questions are more likely to get a good response.

Comment: Thanks.. posted the same query in dba.stackexchange also.